# Why is data not showing on first click? flutter

Tags: database, flutter, sqflite

Why is data not showing on first click?

this is a problem i ran into later. Previously, the data was coming when I first clicked or when the program was first opened, but then I guess I broke a code without realizing it and I can't fix it back please help me

widget's code

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todo/data/todo_service.dart';
import 'package:todo/models/todo.dart';
class TodoListWidget extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return TodoListWidgetState();
  }

}

class TodoListWidgetState extends State<TodoListWidget>{
  TodoService todoService = TodoService.instance;
  List<Todo> todoList = [];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return getTodoList(todoList);

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      loadData();
    });
    super.initState();
  }

    getTodoList(List<Todo> todos)  {

    return  todoList.isEmpty ? Center(child: Text("Nothing to do yet...", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)) :
      ListView.builder(
  itemCount: todos.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return  Card(
      color: const Color(0xffFE7E6D),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children:  [
                Text(
                  todos[index].title!,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Checkbox( value: todos[index].isDone,onChanged:(value){
                     setState(() {
                       todos[index].isDone = value;
                     });
                    },
                    ),
                        IconButton(onPressed: (){
                          setState(() {
                            if(todos[index].isFavourite!){
                              todos[index].isFavourite = false;
                            }
                            else{
                              todos[index].isFavourite = true;
                            }
                          });
                        },
                            icon:  todos[index].isFavourite! ? Icon(Icons.favorite) : Icon(Icons.favorite_border)),
                    IconButton(onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        todoService.deleteTodo(todos[index]);
                        loadData();
                      });

                    },
                        icon: Icon(Icons.delete_outline)),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Container(
              child:  Text(
                todos[index].description!,
                style: TextStyle(
                    letterSpacing: 1, color: Colors.white),
              ),
              color: Colors.transparent,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),);
      },
    );
  }

   void loadData() {
    setState(() {
      todoService.getTodos(false).then((value) {
        todoList = value;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Main screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_advanced_drawer/flutter_advanced_drawer.dart';
import 'package:todo/screens/add_todo_screen.dart';
import 'package:todo/widgets/favourites_widget.dart';
import 'package:todo/widgets/todo_list_widget.dart';
import 'package:todo/widgets/todo_widget.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MainScreenState();
  }
}

class MainScreenState extends State {
  final _advancedDrawerController = AdvancedDrawerController();
  Widget? widgetForBody;
  bool? _floatButton = true;

  @override
  void initState()  {
    setState(() {
      widgetForBody = TodoListWidget();
    });
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AdvancedDrawer(
      backdropColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
      controller: _advancedDrawerController,
      animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
      animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      animateChildDecoration: true,
      rtlOpening: false,
      disabledGestures: false,
      childDecoration: const BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
          shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
          title: const Text('My To Do',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white54,
                  fontSize: 25,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          centerTitle: true,
          leading: IconButton(
            color: Colors.white54,
            onPressed: _handleMenuButtonPressed,
            icon: ValueListenableBuilder<AdvancedDrawerValue>(
              valueListenable: _advancedDrawerController,
              builder: (_, value, __) {
                return AnimatedSwitcher(
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                  child: Icon(
                    value.visible ? Icons.clear : Icons.apps,
                    key: ValueKey<bool>(value.visible),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: widgetForBody,
        floatingActionButton: _floatButton!
            ? FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
           widgetForBody = null;
            });

            goToTodoAdd();
          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.add,
            color: Colors.white54,
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
        )
            : null,
      ),
      drawer: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: ListTileTheme(
            textColor: Colors.white,
            iconColor: Colors.white,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 150,
                ),
                Text(
                  "WELCOME BACK",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white54, fontSize: 20),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                ),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      widgetForBody = TodoListWidget();
                      _advancedDrawerController.value =
                          AdvancedDrawerValue.hidden();
                      _floatButton = true;
                    });
                  },
                  leading: Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank_sharp),
                  title: Text('To Do List',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white54)),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      widgetForBody = TodoWidget();
                      _advancedDrawerController.value =
                          AdvancedDrawerValue.hidden();
                      _floatButton = false;
                    });
                  },
                  leading: Icon(Icons.check_box_outlined),
                  title:
                  Text('History', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white54)),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      widgetForBody = FavouritesWidget();
                      _advancedDrawerController.value =
                          AdvancedDrawerValue.hidden();
                      _floatButton = false;
                    });
                  },
                  leading: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                  title: Text('Favourites',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white54)),
                ),
                Divider(indent: 20, height: 20, color: Colors.grey.shade800),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  leading: Icon(Icons.info_outline),
                  title: Text('Info', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white54)),
                ),
                Spacer(),
                DefaultTextStyle(
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12,
                    color: Colors.white54,
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 16.0,
                    ),
                    child: Text('To Do App Demo'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _handleMenuButtonPressed() {
    // NOTICE: Manage Advanced Drawer state through the Controller.

    _advancedDrawerController.showDrawer();
  }

  void goToTodoAdd() async {
    bool result = await Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddTodoScreen()));
    if (result != null) {
      if (result) {
        setState(() {
          getTodoWidget();
        });
      }
    }
  }

  getTodoWidget() {
    setState(() {
      widgetForBody = TodoListWidget();
    });
  }
}
```

and service

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:todo/models/todo.dart';

class TodoService{
static TodoService instance = TodoService._internal();
TodoService._internal();
Database? _db;
factory TodoService(){
  return instance;
}




   Future<Database?> get db async{
     if(_db == null){
       _db = await _initDb();
     }
     return _db;
   }

  Future<Database> _initDb() async{

    String dbPath = join(await getDatabasesPath(), "todo.db");
    final todoDb = openDatabase(dbPath, version: 1, onCreate: createDb);
    return todoDb;
  }

  void createDb(Database db, int version) async {
     await db.execute("CREATE TABLE todos(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT, description TEXT, isDone INT, isFavourite INT)");
  }

  Future<int> addTodo(Todo todo) async{
     Database? db = await this.db;
    var result = await db!.insert("todos", todo.toMap());
    print(result);
    return result;
  }

  Future<int> updateTodo(Todo todo) async{
     Database? db = await this.db;
     var result = await db!.update("todos", todo.toMap(), where: "id=?", whereArgs: [todo.id]);
     return result;
  }

  Future<int> deleteTodo(Todo todo) async{
     Database? db = await this.db;
     var result = await db!.delete("todos",where: "id=?", whereArgs: [todo.id]);
     return result;
  }

  Future<List<Map<String,dynamic>>?> getTodoMaps()async{
     Database? db = await this.db;
   return await db!.query("todos");
  }

  Future<List<Todo>> getTodos(bool isDone)async{
     final mapList = await getTodoMaps();
     List<Todo> todoList = [];

     mapList?.forEach((element) {
       todoList.add(Todo.fromMap(element));
     });

     if(isDone){
       return todoList.where((element) => element.isDone == true).toList();
     }
     return todoList.where((element) => element.isDone == false).toList();
  }

Future<List<Todo>> getFavouritesTodos()async{
  final mapList = await getTodoMaps();
  List<Todo> todoList = [];

  mapList?.forEach((element) {
    todoList.add(Todo.fromMap(element));
  });
  return todoList.where((element) => element.isFavourite == true).toList();
}
}
```

thank you

Comment: I think its performance issue, you are getting data from database and then showing it using listview builder which build items repeatedly, Before this maybe you are using simple listview

Answer (score 0):

put the setstate inside the then

after you have received the result the screen will be updated

```
void loadData() {
  todoService.getTodos(false).then((value) {
    setState(() {
      todoList = value;
    });
  });
}
```